# secure log file data not up to date, behind a few hours

Tags: rsyslog, rsyslogd

When I `tail -f` my `/var/secure` log file the data in it is about 3 hours behind the current time. This only happens when someone attacks this particular server and the `secure` log files blows up with attempts. Eventually the log file will catch up when the attacks stop.

I have plenty of memory and CPU on the system. Here is `lsof`

`rsyslogd  25935         root    8w      REG              253,1   8786717     269791 /var/log/secure`

It seems like `rsyslogd` is having buffering issues but im not sure how to fix this and it bothers me. I have mitigated the attacks so this doesn't happen very often but I would love to know why this happens.